# In Android how to check if the point from GPS is fitting a given polyline?

Tags: java, android, gps, geocoding, google-polyline

I am having a polyline from the Google directions API. I want to make sure that I get rid of the erroneous GPS coordinate values that can come sometimes. For this, I am thinking of fitting each point which I get from the GPS with the present step polyline. Is there any mathematical or in built functions to do this?

The location coordinates which i get from the LocationListener(GPS) need not be always accurate. SOmetimes this can be inside a buidling near the road also. As i already have an accurate polyline from google API which connects two accurate points, i wanted to confirm that each point which get from the GPS is on or very close to this line.

Comment: Can you first explain what you have in mind with fitting a point with a polyline? What does that mean?

Comment: The functionality i wanted is to detect outliers of a given polyline.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to determine the shortest distance between a point and a polyline?

Comment: `outliers of a given polyline`. Well what would that be? Please take a little effort to explain what you exactly want.

Comment: I don't how to explain more than this, let me try: The location coordinates which I get from the Location Listener(GPS) need not be always accurate. Sometimes this can be inside a building near the road. As i already have an accurate poly line from google API which connects two points, i wanted to confirm that each point which I get from the GPS is on or very close to this line. Hope i am better in explaining this time.

Comment: Yes. That you should have told rigth away of course. Do i understand you correct that you have a polyline that consists of two points only?

Comment: This task is called map matching and is very complex. Especially when multiple of polygons are used, which are parallel and in distance nearer, than the error of the GPS location. And of course: There is no function built in. A single polygon as input is not sufficient. Unless you want to spent some months of work, consider if you need that task and who will pay these developping time

Comment: @greenapps You are correct. A polyline consists of 2 points only.

Comment: @AlexWien i dont know whether i userstood your comment in the right way, here i have no polygons, there are only polylines. And i have to check a point from GPS is around this polyline.

Comment: yes i meant a poly line.

Comment: `A polyline consists of 2 points only.`. No. Normally they consist out of more points then two. But in a collection there might be some with two points only. With two point it's called a line.

Comment: For a moment i thought you described your problem ok and we could start tackling it. But now that you said that your one and only polyline consists of two points only i only can think that that is not true. Are there only three points in play?

Comment: Ok, let me explain you. Google directions api gives two types of polylines( https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=2+brookside+ave,+new+brunswick+,NJ&destination=180+college+ave,+new+brunswick+,NJ&mode=walking&key="Use your directions api key here" ). One is for each step and other for complete route. Complete route polyline looks like this: madvFjbmeMe@iAkBbBsF`CaI`DiBz@eAv@}BqA}FiDWSwBiEqBrBoBrB{D_IaEgIa@^ . If i decode this, will be getting several points. So the above will be group of lines connecting each other. I will get points from GPS based on the refresh rate.

Comment: Two types of polylines? Sorry but i know only one. A group of lines? If you define a polyline you give the coordinates of a number of points. These points you can connect with straight lines. Thats all. Then if you have another point you can ask if that point is near that polyline.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is my requirement.

Comment: @ChristinJose PostGIS is a perfect fit for this task.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference as the question is quite old, check [this](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/#start)
library, its a utility library made for different tasks for android and it has a function in `PolyUtil` class called `isLocationOnPath` which takes a `LatLng point`, a list of points of route and a threshold point for how close you want to check the point for.